# AngularDart - how to get an element from its id?

Tags: angular-dart

(First hours with AngularDart...)

The question's in the title. I have included:

```
import 'package:html/src/query_selector.dart';
```

and my function is:

```
void clickRadio() {
  var ele=querySelector(node,'#idjoe1');
}
```

What do I use for node?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 4):

dart comes with `dart:html` package with a nice query selector

```
import 'dart:html';

var ele = querySelector('#idjoe1');

<div id="idjoe1"></div>
```

but with angular2 you can use the ViewChild annotation inside you component
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.core/ViewChild-class

**EDIT:**
you also need this syntax if you want to use an other Angular2 component

```
@ViewChild('idjoe1')
MaterialRadioComponent radioComponent;

@ViewChild('idjoe2')
ElementRef ref;
HtmlElement get element => ref.nativeElement;

<material-radio #idjoe1></div>
<div #idjoe2></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used dart.html in polymer, but when I tried it here, I defined the type: MaterialRadioComponent ele=querySelector('#idjoe1') , and I thought it was the querySelector that was at fault. So, in Webstorm, if I use Element ele=..., in debug, it shows ele as type "material-radio" (which I can't write as a type in the code). What should I define the type as?

Comment: I updated my answer.
You should follow this tutorial if you have not.
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions you can either inject an `Element` or `HtmlElement` in the constructor (which I think gives you the host element):

```
HtmlElement _host;
MyComponent(this._host);
```

Or you can use `@ViewChild` with an `Element` or `HtmlElement`:

```
@ViewChild('foo')
HtmlElement _foo;

...

<div #foo>
```